# Create relation between enum and tuple-type

Tags: typescript

I am creating a tuple, which is indexable by an enum. To my surprise, this works, as TS understands length of enums and tuples. However, when writing the type of the tuple, i find no way to relate it to the enum:

```
enum E {
  ITEM1,
  ITEM2,
  // ITEM3,
}
declare const e: E;
declare const myTuple: [string, string];
myTuple[e];
```

Uncommenting `ITEM3` will cause an error, i'd have to also add more elements to the tuple, manually. However, the tuple is being generated. I'd much prefer, if editing the enum would suffice (as always, have one central place for changes).

Sadly, afaik TS has no way to convert object keys (e.g. those of an enum) to a tuple-type, even if just the count.

Is there really no better way than when adding an element in the enum, to also add one to the tuple type by hand? I am considering the apocalyptic cast of `as unknown as string[] & Record<E, string>`. While that is extremely unclean, and destroys `.length`, or operations on its type, it's the best i can find so far. Perhaps the sour apple of having two places to edit is still preferable though.

tl;dr; how can i get a tuple-type, which is always indexable by an enum (has the same length)?

Comment: What do you expect `myTuple[e]` to be if `e` is `E.ITEM3` (i.e. `2`)?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WvKJnw) meet your needs?  If so I'll write it up as an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: All items of that tuple will have the same type, in the practical application a structure of textures. `E` itself is used to have a name for these, and as well in lower level operations (e.g. the network protocol uses the same numbers that it has, in its binary protocol, using `E` with bitwise operators is rather common). The array is a table mapping such a name to the related textures, in constant time (dense array, explicitly not a dictionary like an object or a `Map`). The guarantee `myTuple[e]` exists comes from a loading structure being forced to have properties for all enum members.

Comment: @jcalz that's a brilliant idea, i did not think about this way of using enum elements being integers counting up - so it is possible after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
type EnumToTuple<T extends number, V, A extends V[] = []> =
    `${T}` extends keyof A ? A : EnumToTuple<T, V, [...A, V]>
```

`EnumToTuple<T, V>` is a [tail-recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) that starts with the empty tuple and keeps appending `V` to it until it has the "same length" as the `T` numeric enum.  Well, it keeps appending until the tuple has keys corresponding to the stringified versions of the `T` enum.

So for this:

```
enum E {
    ITEM1,
    ITEM2,
    ITEM3,
}
declare const e: E;

type ETuple = EnumToTuple<E, string>;
// type ETuple = [string, string, string]
```

the `EnumToTuple<E, string>` type keeps appending `string` to the accumulated tuple until `"0" | "1" | "2"` are its keys, which first happens at `[string, string, string]`.  And that means a value of type `ETuple` is known to have a `string` property at keys of type `E`:

```
declare const myTuple: ETuple
myTuple[e].toUpperCase(); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAolDeBYAUFNUCSAVGBZAjADQrqY64BMxq62eAzNQL4oAmwAxgDYCGATsCgcA9iADOAFyjAAXLADcKFBICeAB0ExwELMKxg1XYAB4s0gB4TQrMVG0AjYH0JQAai4CCFqyBtuA2gC6UAC8UEEAfKEk6AAGACTwWEyx3ta2ANbAKsIAZlBeAPwFUHJakLr6hiZYLu7hAHRNHnWBEUrIqhqwVUahsNqVBkbGMC6SfACWIADmEYrIAPSLUF2avYJh-hPTM+MSU7P7hzOBHezc-IIi4lIQKhtlGyj3G-7AgQ0SwgCqahp8ADCPDEwAAFABKeRQZZQYQZHgqIA)